# Error when splitting function argument interval into separate parts. Parallel Python

Tags: python, eof, parallel-python

First off, sorry for all the code. I'm having a hard time formulating a specific question. I have tinkered with this for a while and just can't get it to work. The error message hasn't been very helpful. I would greatly appreciate a little help.

I want to execute three instances of my function 'EMatCreatorrx(umin,umax,vmin,vmax,stepsize,pstep,alphamax,A,rot):' for different argument ranges in parallel in order to speed up computation.

umin, umax and vmin, vmax both define a range of values to be calculated in the u and v direction respectively. I want to divide the function by breaking the u range into three smaller ranges.

I have demonstrated that my code for splicing the function into three separate parts and then rejoining works correctly by running the following:

```
import pp
import sys

import numpy as N
import scipy as sp
from scipy import integrate as Int
from scipy import special as S
import math

cos=sp.cos
sin=sp.sin
exp=sp.exp
sqrt=sp.sqrt
j=S.jn
pi=N.pi
floor=N.floor

def EMatCreatorrx(umin,umax,vmin,vmax,stepsize,pstep,alphamax,A,rot): #pstep needs to be pi/n for n=0,1,2,3,... This is so there will be an odd number of samples when calculating the PSF. This is necessary to increase the accuracy of Simpson's method.   
    mnum=N.int(((umax-umin)/stepsize)+1)
    nnum=N.int(((vmax-vmin)/stepsize)+1)
    pnum=N.int((2*pi/pstep)+1)
    gridshape=(mnum,nnum,pnum)
    I0=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    I1=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    I2=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    E01=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex) 
    E02=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex) 
    E03=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    for m,u in enumerate(N.linspace(umin,umax,num=mnum)):
        for n,v in enumerate(N.linspace(vmin,vmax,num=nnum)):
            for i,p in enumerate(N.linspace(0,2*pi,num=pnum)):             
                vp = sqrt((v*cos(p))**2 + (v*sin(p)*cos(rot)-u*sin(rot))**2)
                up = (v*cos(p)*sin(rot) + u*cos(rot))
                pp= N.arctan2(v*sin(p)*cos(rot) - u*sin(rot), v*cos(p))  
                I0real=lambda theta: N.real((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1+cos(theta))*  (j(0,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I0imaginary=lambda theta: N.imag((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1+cos(theta))*(j(0,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I0real_integral= Int.quad(I0real, 0, alphamax)
                I0imag_integral= Int.quad(I0imaginary, 0, alphamax)
                I1real=lambda theta: N.real(sqrt(cos(theta))*((sin(theta))**2)*j(1,vp*sin(theta)/(sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I1imaginary=lambda theta: N.imag(sqrt(cos(theta))*((sin(theta))**2)*j(1,vp*sin(theta)/(sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I1real_integral= Int.quad(I1real, 0, alphamax)
                I1imag_integral= Int.quad(I1imaginary, 0, alphamax)
                I2real=lambda theta: N.real((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1-cos(theta))*(j(2,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I2imaginary=lambda theta: N.imag((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1-cos(theta))*(j(2,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))   
                I2real_integral= Int.quad(I2real, 0, alphamax)
                I2imag_integral= Int.quad(I2imaginary, 0, alphamax)
                I0.real[m,n,i]=I0real_integral[0]
                I0.imag[m,n,i]=I0imag_integral[0]
                I1.real[m,n,i]=I1real_integral[0]
                I1.imag[m,n,i]=I1imag_integral[0]
                I2.real[m,n,i]=I2real_integral[0]
                I2.imag[m,n,i]=I2imag_integral[0]
                E01[m,n,i]=-A*(1j*(I0[m,n,i]+I2[m,n,i]*cos(2*pp)))
                E02[m,n,i]=-A*(cos(rot)*1j*I2[m,n,i]*sin(2*pp) - sin(rot)*2*I1[m,n,i]*cos(pp))
                E03[m,n,i]=-A*(sin(rot)*1j*I2[m,n,i]*sin(2*pp) + cos(rot)*2*I1[m,n,i]*cos(pp))
    return E01,E02,E03,pstep


#EMatCreatorrx(umin,umax,vmin,vmax,stepsize,pstep,alphamax,A,rot): #Enter parameters below in tuple "params."

params=-2,2,-2,2,.2,N.pi/10,1,1,0
##############################################################################################################

mnum=N.int(((params[1]-params[0])/params[4])+1)
nnum=N.int(((params[3]-params[2])/params[4])+1)
pnum=N.int((2*N.pi/params[5])+1)
phold=N.zeros((mnum,nnum,pnum), dtype=complex),N.zeros((mnum,nnum,pnum), dtype=complex),N.zeros((mnum,nnum,pnum), dtype=complex), params[5]

uindarr = [(m, u) for m,u in enumerate(N.linspace(params[0],params[1],num=mnum))]

ind_end1=floor(len(uindarr)/3)
spa_end1=uindarr[int(ind_end1)][1]

ind_beg2=ind_end1+1
spa_beg2=uindarr[int(ind_beg2)][1]
ind_end2=2*floor(len(uindarr)/3)
spa_end2=uindarr[int(ind_end2)][1]

ind_beg3=ind_end2+1
spa_beg3=uindarr[int(ind_beg3)][1]

job1 = EMatCreatorrx(params[0],spa_end1,params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5],params[6],params[7],params[8]) 
job2 = EMatCreatorrx(spa_beg2,spa_end2,params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5],params[6],params[7],params[8])
job3 = EMatCreatorrx(spa_beg3,params[1],params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5],params[6],params[7],params[8])

phold[0][:ind_end1+1,:,:]=job1[0]
phold[0][ind_beg2:ind_end2+1,:,:]=job2[0]
phold[0][ind_beg3:,:,:]=job3[0]

phold[1][:ind_end1+1,:,:]=job1[1]
phold[1][ind_beg2:ind_end2+1,:,:]=job2[1]
phold[1][ind_beg3:,:,:]=job3[1]

phold[2][:ind_end1+1,:,:]=job1[2]
phold[2][ind_beg2:ind_end2+1,:,:]=job2[2]
phold[2][ind_beg3:,:,:]=job3[2]
```

After this worked, I attempted to implement parallel python in order to compute the three slices in parallel using this code:

```
import pp
import sys

import numpy as N
import scipy as sp
from scipy import integrate as Int
from scipy import special as S
import math

cos=sp.cos
sin=sp.sin
exp=sp.exp
sqrt=sp.sqrt
j=S.jn
pi=sp.pi
floor=N.floor

def EMatCreatorrx(umin,umax,vmin,vmax,stepsize,pstep,alphamax,A,rot): #pstep needs to be pi/n for n=0,1,2,3,... This is so there will be an odd number of samples when calculating the PSF. This is necessary to increase the accuracy of Simpson's method.   
    cos=sp.cos
    sin=sp.sin
    exp=sp.exp
    sqrt=sp.sqrt
    j=S.jn
    pi=sp.pi  
    mnum=N.int(((umax-umin)/stepsize)+1)
    nnum=N.int(((vmax-vmin)/stepsize)+1)
    pnum=N.int((2*pi/pstep)+1)
    gridshape=(mnum,nnum,pnum)
    I0=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    I1=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    I2=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    E01=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex) 
    E02=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex) 
    E03=N.zeros(gridshape,dtype=complex)
    for m,u in enumerate(N.linspace(umin,umax,num=mnum)):
        for n,v in enumerate(N.linspace(vmin,vmax,num=nnum)):
            for i,p in enumerate(N.linspace(0,2*pi,num=pnum)):             
                vp = sqrt((v*cos(p))**2 + (v*sin(p)*cos(rot)-u*sin(rot))**2)
                up = (v*cos(p)*sin(rot) + u*cos(rot))
                pp= N.arctan2(v*sin(p)*cos(rot) - u*sin(rot), v*cos(p))  
                I0real=lambda theta: N.real((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1+cos(theta))*(j(0,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I0imaginary=lambda theta: N.imag((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1+cos(theta))*(j(0,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I0real_integral= Int.quad(I0real, 0, alphamax)
                I0imag_integral= Int.quad(I0imaginary, 0, alphamax)
                I1real=lambda theta: N.real(sqrt(cos(theta))*((sin(theta))**2)*j(1,vp*sin(theta)/(sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I1imaginary=lambda theta: N.imag(sqrt(cos(theta))*((sin(theta))**2)*j(1,vp*sin(theta)/(sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I1real_integral= Int.quad(I1real, 0, alphamax)
                I1imag_integral= Int.quad(I1imaginary, 0, alphamax)
                I2real=lambda theta: N.real((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1-cos(theta))*(j(2,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))
                I2imaginary=lambda theta: N.imag((sqrt(cos(theta))*sin(theta))*(1-cos(theta))*(j(2,vp*sin(theta)/sin(alphamax)))*exp((1j*up*cos(theta))/((sin(alphamax))**2)))   
                I2real_integral= Int.quad(I2real, 0, alphamax)
                I2imag_integral= Int.quad(I2imaginary, 0, alphamax)
                I0.real[m,n,i]=I0real_integral[0]
                I0.imag[m,n,i]=I0imag_integral[0]
                I1.real[m,n,i]=I1real_integral[0]
                I1.imag[m,n,i]=I1imag_integral[0]
                I2.real[m,n,i]=I2real_integral[0]
                I2.imag[m,n,i]=I2imag_integral[0]
                E01[m,n,i]=-A*(1j*(I0[m,n,i]+I2[m,n,i]*cos(2*pp)))
                E02[m,n,i]=-A*(cos(rot)*1j*I2[m,n,i]*sin(2*pp) - sin(rot)*2*I1[m,n,i]*cos(pp))
                E03[m,n,i]=-A*(sin(rot)*1j*I2[m,n,i]*sin(2*pp) + cos(rot)*2*I1[m,n,i]*cos(pp))
    return E01,E02,E03,pstep






#EMatCreatorrx(umin,umax,vmin,vmax,stepsize,pstep,alphamax,A,rot): #Enter parameters below in tuple "params."

params=-2,2,-2,2,.2,N.pi/10,1,1,0
##############################################################################################################

mnum=N.int(((params[1]-params[0])/params[4])+1)
nnum=N.int(((params[3]-params[2])/params[4])+1)
pnum=N.int((2*N.pi/params[5])+1)
phold=N.zeros((mnum,nnum,pnum), dtype=complex),N.zeros((mnum,nnum,pnum), dtype=complex),N.zeros((mnum,nnum,pnum), dtype=complex), params[5]

uindarr = [(m, u) for m,u in enumerate(N.linspace(params[0],params[1],num=mnum))]

ind_end1=floor(len(uindarr)/3)
spa_end1=uindarr[int(ind_end1)][1]

ind_beg2=ind_end1+1
spa_beg2=uindarr[int(ind_beg2)][1]
ind_end2=2*floor(len(uindarr)/3)
spa_end2=uindarr[int(ind_end2)][1]

ind_beg3=ind_end2+1
spa_beg3=uindarr[int(ind_beg3)][1]

ppservers = ()
job_server = pp.Server()
fn = pp.Template(job_server, EMatCreatorrx, (), ("scipy as sp", "numpy as N", "scipy.special as S", "scipy.integrate as Int",))
job1 = fn.submit(params[0],spa_end1,params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5],params[6],params[7],params[8]) 
job2 = fn.submit(spa_beg2,spa_end2,params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5],params[6],params[7],params[8])
job3 = fn.submit(spa_beg3,params[1],params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5],params[6],params[7],params[8])

phold[0][:ind_end1+1,:,:]=job1[0]
phold[0][ind_beg2:ind_end2+1,:,:]=job2[0]
phold[0][ind_beg3:,:,:]=job3[0]

phold[1][:ind_end1+1,:,:]=job1[1]
phold[1][ind_beg2:ind_end2+1,:,:]=job2[1]
phold[1][ind_beg3:,:,:]=job3[1]

phold[2][:ind_end1+1,:,:]=job1[2]
phold[2][ind_beg2:ind_end2+1,:,:]=job2[2]
phold[2][ind_beg3:,:,:]=job3[2]


print "computation complete"
```

When I try to run the code above, I get the following End of File error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Desktop\Python Path\parallel python\parallel2.py", line 104, in <module>
    job1 = fn.submit((params[0],spa_end1,params[2],params[3],params[4],params[5],params[6],params[7],params[8])) 
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Desktop\Python Path\parallel python\pp.py", line 270, in submit
    self.group, self.globals)
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Desktop\Python Path\parallel python\pp.py", line 459, in submit
    sfunc = self.__dumpsfunc((func, ) + depfuncs, modules)
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Desktop\Python Path\parallel python\pp.py", line 637, in __dumpsfunc
    sources = [self.__get_source(func) for func in funcs]
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Desktop\Python Path\parallel python\pp.py", line 704, in __get_source
    sourcelines = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0]
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 693, in getsourcelines
    else: return getblock(lines[lnum:]), lnum + 1
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 677, in getblock
    tokenize.tokenize(iter(lines).next, blockfinder.tokeneater)
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Python27\lib\tokenize.py", line 169, in tokenize
    tokenize_loop(readline, tokeneater)
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Python27\lib\tokenize.py", line 175, in tokenize_loop
    for token_info in generate_tokens(readline):
  File "C:\Users\tph89\Python27\lib\tokenize.py", line 296, in generate_tokens
    raise TokenError, ("EOF in multi-line string", strstart)
tokenize.TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line string', (2, 0))
```

At this point, I am a little lost. Have any of you encountered this error before? If so, what was the issue? Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here.

Comment: And that error typically means you have an unclosed `'`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well when using Parallel Python, also due to a tokenize error. In my case, one of my helper functions had double indentation (eight spaces, due to a copy paste phenomenon, while the function declaration was in the right indentation level of zero spaces) - Spyder's main interpreter just dealt with this, but tokenize apparently does not.

In the OP's case: based on the way the code is formatted above, and based on the comment at the top of [tokenize](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/tokenize.py) here, the error likely happened because there is no white space on the empty lines; this would return "" which the comment says is handled as EOF.